# What is wrong with this Redux applyMiddleware because it only works with one

Tags: react-redux

I learn React Redux and if I have one `middleware` function in the index.js and importing it into the configureStore.js everything works like this:

```
const middlewares = [forbiddenWordsMiddleware, thunk]
const store = createStore(
  reduce,
  storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
export default store;
```

When I add another `middleware` the `getDataMiddleware` like this:

```
const middlewares = [forbiddenWordsMiddleware, getDataMiddleware, thunk]
const store = createStore(
  reduce,
  storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
export default store;
```

I get the error in the other forbiddenWordsMiddleware like this:

```
TypeError: next is not a function
(anonymous function)
L:/react/redux-tutorial/src/js/middleware/index.js:19
  16 |                     return dispatch(addBadWword(foundWord));
  17 |                 }
  18 |             }
> 19 |             return next(action);
  20 |         };
  21 |     };
  22 | }
```

The functions are exported/imported correctly I think 
I added a picture showing the files and the error:

[image: can]

Answer (score 1):

`getDataMiddleware` second function receives `next` middleware's dispatch method. seems like you mistakenly named it `dispatch`.

Comment: Thanks I´m way off with this code. I´m going through [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/) tutorial on Redux.